# CheckGMail, aMSN in notification area won't use the gnome-panel background

Tags: gnome-panel, transparency

When I use CheckGMail, it shows up in Notification Area.
But it never use gnome-panel's background color. It looks like something wrong with the panel.

Same goes with aMSN.

Is there a way to fix it? Or change theme to cover this up. I am now using Elementary theme.

Answer (score 3):

New version of **CheckGMail** (from PPA or in "check updates" command from tray icon menu), as far as I know, have that bug fixed.

BTW, **gmail-notify** have nicer integration with app-indicators. Try it.

Comment: This is a known bug of aMSN: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/amsn/+bug/582567

Comment: I don't use aMSN, sorry..

Answer (score 0):

Change ur panel background color until they fix the bug. Just delete or rename panel.png in /usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0 and you will be able to change the color of your panel.

Answer (score 0):

You could use gmail-notify as Extender said, but you should also switch to emesene, instead of amsn, because amsn is almost dead (still under development, but going so slow you don't get a release for months).